# I can't change the status code response on a call ASP MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

How can I change the status code response on a call ASP MVC 5 Controller?
I'm trying doing something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       ...
    }

    Response.StatusCode = 401; 
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
}
```

And when I'm doing an ajax call, I'm still getting 200 status code response.
Any idea to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a `return` inside the `if` block?

Comment: Yes, but I need the `return` outside the `if` block returns a 401 status code when the login failed

Comment: What I'm getting at is perhaps it's getting through the login code without any problem and correctly returning a 200. Try stepping through it to ensure it actually hits the code in question.